# MySQL NOT EXISTS not compiling. 3 errors were found

Tags: mysql, subquery, not-exists

I am learning subqueries in MYSQL. I was reading this 
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx)
 link and
[dev.mysql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx)
  link regarding **EXISTS** and **NOT EXISTS** in subquery.

Following the approach, i wrote the query

```
SELECT p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
FROM 
people as p
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM loan as l WHERE l.people_id = p.id);
```

This query is not compiling and giving errors. The screen shot of errors is attached

[image: Error Descriptoin]

P.S I am using PhpMyAdmin. I am trying to return a list of people who have no loans

My Database Schema is as follows

table # 1

[image: People Table]

loan table

[image: loan table structure]

people_id is foreign key referring to the id of 'people' table. But for this query it is not concerned.

I am unable to understand why the errors are occuring. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: your query looks fine ... is that the query you are trying? make sure you have no special character there

Comment: Your screenshot does not match the query you posted.  `LIMIT` maybe can't be used inside the subquery of an `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It did not show the complete query due to error

Comment: `LIMIT 0,25 at line 4` is mentioned in the actual error message **So, what is the actual complete query you used please?** (please add it to the question) because the partial query you have included so far has no syntax errors.